# Laravel orWhere giving unexpected result

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query.

```
  $bid_check        =     Bidders::where([

                                          'project_id'  =>    $id,

                                          'status'      =>    1,

                                          'active'      =>    1,

                                        ])

                                        ->orWhere([

                                                  'project_id'  =>    $id,

                                                  'status'      =>    2,

                                                  'active'      =>    1

                                                ])

                                ->first();

                                print_r($bid_check);die;
```

When I write it without orWhere it is showing no results which are okay, but when I write orWhere it gives me the first column of the database which is wrong. The condition in where and orWhere do not match with any of the columns in the DB. So, it should return empty, but it is returning the first column of DB. Why is it returning a value, has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better if you use a whereIn function

```
Bidders::where(['project_id'=>$id,'active'=>1])
         ->whereIn('status', [1,2])
         ->first();
```

i think the array in the `orWhere` is create as a list of or clauses not as a and clause so you will have `or project_id = $id or active = 1 or status = 2`

if the above is true then you should do the following

```
->orWhere(function($query) {
     return $query->where([
       'project_id'  =>    $id,
       'status'      =>    2,
       'active'      =>    1
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks more optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Bidders::where('project_id', $id)
         ->where('active', 1)
         ->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('status', 1)
                   ->orWhere('status', 2);
         })->first();
```

Comment: It works, can you please explain to me what have you done, I have never used a function in where. Or any source from where I can read about it. And how was mine wrong?

Comment: dump raw sql for every statement, for example `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Bidders::where('project_id', $id)
         ->where('active', 1)
         ->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('status', 1)
                   ->orWhere('status', 2);
         })->first();  dd(
            DB::getQueryLog()
        );`

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
 Bidders::where(function ($query) {
         $query->orWhere([  'project_id'  =>    $id
                            'active'      =>    1
                         ])
               ->orWhere('status', 1)
               ->orWhere('status', 3)
               ->orWhere('status', 2);
       })->get();
```

Comment: this code return rows with `2` status only, need `1` and `2`

Comment: It throws an error, and instead of get() I need 1 row, so will first.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$bid_check =     Bidders::where('active', 1)
                            ->where('project_id', $id)
                            ->where(function ($query) {
                                   $query->where('status', 1)->orWhere('status', 2);
                             })
                           ->first();
```